# Largest sum contiguous subarray (Interview Question)

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the maximum interval sum in a list of real numbers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331040/find-the-maximum-interval-sum-in-a-list-of-real-numbers)

I was asked the following question today at Adobe interview for the position of software engineer.

**Problem**  Given a array `arr[1..n]` of integers. Write an algorithm to find the sum of contiguous subarray within the array which has the largest sum. Return 0 if all the numbers are negative.

**Example**

Given array `arr[1..6] = [ 12, 14, 0, -4, 61, -39 ]`

**Answer**

83 constructed with `[ 12, 14, 0, -4, 61 ]`.

I could come up with a solution running in `O(n logn)` but I don't think it was very efficient. The interviewer asked to me to write an `O(n)` algorithm. I couldn't come up with it.

Any idea about how to write an `O(n)` solution for this problem?
Algorithm to be implemented either in C/C++/Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a whole chapter on this problem in "Programming Pearls" -- recommended reading.

Comment: It is a very simple problem. Traverse from both ends one by one. And keep trimming the array from each end until the sum from starting to current position or from end to current position is negative. O(n)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) which runs in O(n).

Here is the algorithm (shamelessly copied from [here](http://geeksforgeeks.org/?p=576))

```
Initialize:
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0

Loop for each element of the array
  (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
  (b) if(max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0
  (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
return max_so_far
```

Comment: Here's a link to the wikipedia article for reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: What about this array: [ -12, 14, 0, -4, 61, -39 ]              Actual result: [ -12, 14, 0, -4, 61]                         Expected: [14, 0, -4, 61]