# Max subarray hints needed

Tags: java, algorithm

> Find the contiguous subarray within an array (containing at least one
>   number) which has the largest sum.
>
> For example, given the array [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4], the contiguous
>   subarray [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.

I am unable to solve this problem, **but I would just like some hints.**

It it said this can be solved using Dynamic Programming, but I am struggling to see a connection.

Would the DP connection be taking the sum of the **whole** array?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Largest sum contiguous subarray (Interview Question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378273/largest-sum-contiguous-subarray-interview-question)

Comment: Here's a hint for you. Let's say your array is `A[n]`. Now build another array `B[n]` such that `B[k]` contains the contiguous subarray in `A` with the biggest sum starting *exactly* at `A[k]`. And, as it's typical in DP, build It from the end -- `B[n]` is obviously just one-element array `A[n]`. Knowing that, can you determine `B[n-1]`?...

Answer (score -1):

A reference for your problem can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

You must use the Kadane's algorithm to solve such a case, which goes something like this:

```
Initialize:
    max_so_far = 0
    max_ending_here = 0

Loop for each element of the array
    (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i]
    (b) if(max_ending_here < 0)
        max_ending_here = 0
    (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here)
        max_so_far = max_ending_here
    return max_so_far
```

A sample code for your reference:

```
static int maxSubArraySum(int a[])
{
    int size = a.length;
    int max_so_far = Integer.MIN_VALUE, max_ending_here = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i];
        if (max_so_far < max_ending_here)
            max_so_far = max_ending_here;
        if (max_ending_here < 0)
            max_ending_here = 0;
    }
    return max_so_far;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a hint; it looks like a coded answer.

Comment: @user3773048, I have added the necessary hint and enhanced the answer to provide some more details. This doesn't need to be downvoted for this reason, IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

PLease find Java Code.

```
public static void findMaxSubArray(int arr[]){

    int max_end_her=arr[0];
    int max_so_far=arr[0];

    int x=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        max_end_her=Math.max(x, max_end_her+arr[i]);
        max_so_far=Math.max(max_so_far, max_end_her);   
    }



System.out.println(max_so_far); 

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a hint; it looks like a coded answer.