# Largest contiguous sum

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find the maximum interval sum in a list of real numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331040/find-the-maximum-interval-sum-in-a-list-of-real-numbers)

Below is my dp expression to solve this:

```
lcs[i] = { max(lcs[i-1] + x[i], x[i])}
```

where lcs[i] is the longest contiguous sum till index i and also including element x[i]. However, i dont know why we define lcs[i] to also include x[i]. Can't we just define lcs[i] as the longest contiguous sum  till index i.

Comment: Probably because this question comes along regularly, and there are plenty of answers and discussions about it already.

Comment: Most likely -1 as this isn't an appropriate place for interview questions. I didn't -1 myself, but an interview is meant to evaluate *your* skills, not your ability to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just define `lcs[i]` as `lcs[i-1]+x[i]` because of the possibility of negative numbers in the list.

Consider the list `x={-1, 1}`.

```
lcs[0] = -1
lcs[1] = max(-1+1,1) = 1 != -1+1
```

If your list was strictly non-negative, then yes, you could define `lcs[i]=lcs[i-1]+x[i]`. But notice that this recursive definition translates directly to a sum over all `x[i]`. This agrees to the intuitive notion that the maximum contiguous sum of a list of positive numbers is simply the sum of all the elements in the list.